# I was told this painting was written in small seal script. I dont speak any chinese. Can anyone translate it for me? (Characters identified: 天光時來四景開拓)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I inherited this painting from my grandmother, so I don't have any information about it's origin. She lived in China around 1965 or 1966, but don't know if it was purchased there.[image]

Comment: You already got an answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Chinese/comments/1bmvao8/comment/kwev622/

Comment: @dROOOze, “六” lah, not “四” 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I originally thought it was 「六」 too, but the lack of dot on the top doesn't make sense. Then I saw the 說文古文 entry for [「四」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/xiaozhuan?kaiOrder=218) (「」).

Comment: @dROOOze, i see, then “四” is more likely, my apologies 